# Are all chainring compatible with all chain?

Tags: chain, crankset, chainring, drivetrain

I want to change my drivetrain on my bike and i found everything except the chainring. So I was wondering if I could choose any chainring. 
Thank for yours response.

Comment: Pretty much all modern bicycles use a chain with a half-inch spacing between links, so any chainring will match from that standpoint.  However, there are 4 different common widths for the chain, and the chainring needs to match in width as well.  https://bike.bikegremlin.com/3555/bicycle-drive-chain-dimension-standards/

Comment: The BCD and bolt count is important to match as well - a 4 bolt spider won't hold a 5 bolt chainring, and there are at least 3 patterns of 4 bolts.  Plus a bunch of different diameters.

Comment: You also have to look out for narrow-wide chainrings, which aren't compatible with front derailleurs.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The chainring needs to be compatible with the rest of the drivetrain.

Chainring pitch (width + spacing) gets tighter with increased cogs on the rear wheel. So a 9 speed chainring is not compatible with an 11 speed drivetrain.  Additionally there are new narrow-wide chainrings for single chainring setups will not work well in a system with a front derailleur.